# Syntax regions ignoring "contains" requirement

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've got this in my vim buffer:

```
* [ ] set up adding asterisk or changing color automatically when a task is annotated ==ANN==  #9f359cd0
* [ ] write documentation in ## Notes section  #7226ec9c
```

I want to highlight the first line with the ==ANN== in red. So I have this:

```
syntax region Annotation start=/==AN/ end=/N==/ containedin=TaskWikiTask,VimwikiListTodo
hi Annotation ctermfg=black

syntax region TaskWithAnn start=/\]\s\+/rs=e+1,hs=e+1 end=/#/re=e-1,he=e-1 oneline contains=Annotation containedin=VimwikiListTodo,TaskWikiTask
hi TaskWithAnn ctermfg=red
```

It highlights the first line, but the second line is also in red and I'm not sure why. I thought the "contains" modifier would only highlight regions that contain an `Annotation` region.

Answer (score 3):

I can see you've already come up with a solution for your problem, but for the benefit of posterity, I thought I'd explain what was wrong with your original code, which is that you're mistaken about what `contains` does.

`contains=Annotation` *doesn't* mean that `TaskWithAnn` will only match regions that contain an `Annotation` region. It means that `TaskWithAnn` regions are *allowed* to contain `Annotation` regions.

See [`:help :syn-contains`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-contains) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out. Went with this, no need for the `contains`:

```
syntax region Annotation start=/==AN/ end=/N==/ containedin=TaskWikiTask,VimwikiListTodo
hi Annotation ctermfg=black

syntax region TaskWithAnn start=/\]\s\+/rs=e+1,hs=e+1 end=/==ANN==/re=e-8 oneline containedin=TaskWikiTask,VimwikiListTodo
hi TaskWithAnn ctermfg=red
```

Comment: You can do `:syntax keyword Annotation ===ANN=== containedin=…`, for the record